# Calling a derived function from an array of the base class

Tags: c++, arrays, virtual, derived

How do you call a derived function from an array of the base class?

Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class a{

public:
    virtual void prnt(){
        std::cout<<"a"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class b: public a{

public:
    virtual void prnt(){
        std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    a array[3];
    array[0] = a();
    array[1] = b();
    array[2] = a();

    array[1].prnt();
}
```

The output for this example is `a`.

is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: _is there anyway to fix this._ Fix it how?

Comment: `b` is not a possible output for this code. Did you mean `a` ?

Comment: yes. A is what I meant. Sorry, its late here.

Comment: You can't because it's an array of the base class, which means the objects in it are of the base class, not the derived class, so you can't call derived class functions on it because it's not the derived class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Justin commented, you're witnessing a case of [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/2422776). One way to get the behavior you're expecting is to use pointers:

```
int main() {
    a* array[3];
    array[0] = new a();
    array[1] = new b();
    array[2] = new a();

    array[1]->prnt();

    // Don't forget to delete them!
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        delete array[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 array[1] = b();
```

The above is object slicing.Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Polymorphism works with pointers and references only.

```
 a *array[3];
 array[0] = new a();
 array[1] = new b();
 array[2] = new a();

 array[1]->print()
```